# Is it good to open a new database connection or keep a connection open until process completes?

Tags: java, groovy, mybatis

I have 2 databases `old` & `new`, `old` db detail needs to be filtered/manipulated and stored into `new`.

> `OLD DB`

1. I have around 10000 configurations (DB rows)
2. and 10000 BLOBS (xml file size is 4MB on an average) matching config id's from above

> `NEW DB`

1. 1 new table that is going to contain the filtered data from old, but this time no BLOB data, instead absolute paths
2. and per configuration some recommendations

Here I wrote a program (using Groovy & MyBatis for DB) which gets all the configuration records available in `OLD DB` and stores in a List of class and the DB Connection is closed

In order to fetch the BLOBS too for each config id, a new connection is established & is kept open for a long time

```
List<String> projectid
List<CSMConfigInfo> oldConfigs
List<ConfigInfo> newConfigs 
Map<String,CSMConfigInfo> oldConfigMap

SqlSession session = DatabaseConnectivity.getOldCSMDBSessionFactory().openSession()
/*  trying to batch execute based on project id */
    projectid.each {pid->
        logger.info "Initiating conversion for all configuration under $pid project id"
        oldConfigMap.each {k,v->
/*  Here I am keeping a DB connection open for a long time */           
            if(pid.equals(v)){                  
                createFromBlob(k,session)                   
            }
        }                       
        logger.info "Completed for $pid project id\n"           
    }

session.close()
```

After fetching the BLOB 1 by 1, I create a temp xml file which is parsed to apply the filter for inserting into `NEW DB`. Below code you can see that based on whether xml is convertible and parsible a new connection is opened for `NEW DB`. Is this good practice or do I need to keep the `NEW DB` connection open for all 10000 records?

```
/* XML is converted to new format and is parsable */
def createFromBlob(CSMConfigInfo cfg,SqlSession oldCSMSession){
    .
    .

    if(xmlConverted&&xmlParsed){
        //DB Entries
        try{
            /* So now here I am opening a new connection for every old config record, which can be 10000 times too, depending on the filter */
            SqlSession sess = DatabaseConnectivity.getNewCSMSessionFactory().openSession()

            //New CSM Config
            makeDatabaseEntriesForConfiguration(newConfig,sess)
            //Fire Rules
            fireRules(newConfig,sess,newCSMRoot)

            sess.close()

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            logger.info "Exception with ${newConfig.getCfgId().toString()} while making DB entries for CONFIG_INFO"
        }
        logger.info "Config id: "+cfg.getCfgId().toString()+" completed successfully, took "+getElapsedTime(startTime)+ " time. $newabspath"
    }
    else{
        def errormsg = null
        if(!xmlConverted&&!xmlParsed)
            errormsg = "Error while CONVERSION & PARSING of config id "+cfg.getCfgId().toString()+", took "+getElapsedTime(startTime)+ " time."
        else if(!xmlConverted)
            errormsg = "Error while CONVERSION of config id "+cfg.getCfgId().toString()+", took "+getElapsedTime(startTime)+ " time."
        else if(!xmlParsed)
            errormsg = "Error while PARSING  of config id "+cfg.getCfgId().toString()+", took "+getElapsedTime(startTime)+ " time."
        logger.info errormsg
    }

    makeDatabaseEntriesForConvertStatus(csmConfigConvertStatus,oldCSMSession)
}
```

This currently works for 20 records, but I am not sure how will it react for all 10000 records. Please help

**Update**

I takes about 3-6 secs for each config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will always be more efficient to use a pool of database connections, let a container manage establishing and closing that connection when required. Creating a connection, executing your statement and then closing that connection can be avoided with a pool which will pre-connect before giving you the connection to use and in most cases (particulars for what you described) the connection will not need to be made given it will likely be connected already.

So therefore yes it is more efficient to keep the connection open and even better to pool your connections...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. MyBatis does not take care of connection pooling? Do you know of any resource which I can follow for DB connection pool?

Comment: I would look at http://grails.org/plugin/jdbc-pool perhaps to achieve what you require. Alternatively you can just create a number of connections yourself and don't close them till your code finishes doing what it needs to...

Comment: Any resource for MyBatis connection pooling. I am not using Grails :(

Comment: @AbhishekSimon There seems to be instructions for pooled datasources [in the documentation for MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/core/configuration.html#environments)

Comment: @tim_yates: Thanks it improved with 54 secs for 13 records

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding glad you were able to resolve the problem though.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, there is usually an overhead when you create a new connection within each cycle of a loop. If it takes 0.1 seconds to open a connection, then for 10000 records, your time overhead will be  1,000 seconds (that's about 17 minutes). If you kept the connection open and not close it while you go over the 10,000 records, you would save 17 minutes. I think you will want to save 17 minutes as well as the CPU resource required to close and re-create a connection 10,000 times. Open the connection outside your loop, and close it after your loop.

Try modify the method `createFromBlob` so that it will accept two sessions like this;

`def createFromBlob(CSMConfigInfo cfg,SqlSession oldCSMSession, SqlSession newCSMSession){`

Then replace this code block;

```
        /* So now here I am opening a new connection for every old config record, which can be 10000 times too, depending on the filter */
        SqlSession sess = DatabaseConnectivity.getNewCSMSessionFactory().openSession()

        //New CSM Config
        makeDatabaseEntriesForConfiguration(newConfig,sess)
        //Fire Rules
        fireRules(newConfig,sess,newCSMRoot)

        sess.close()
```

With this;

```
 //New CSM Config
        makeDatabaseEntriesForConfiguration(newConfig,newCSMSession)
        //Fire Rules
        fireRules(newConfig,newCSMSession,newCSMRoot)
```

Then you will have to create pass the new SqlSession right before you start looping, and pass it to the method you've modified ( `createFromBlob` )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It usually takes approximately 5 secs for each record

Comment: You're welcome. Create two connections outside both loops and keep them alive. That should be just before the line ` projectid.each {pid->`. That should save you the overhead. You can mark my answer as the correct one if it helps ;)

Comment: if 5 sec, then as this answer said the pool of connection will be better, sounds you don't have operation about CLOB or other complex type in database.

Comment: Try see the edit in my answer right now, then see how long, on average, processing each record takes. This way you should be able to eliminate the overhead that was there of creating an sql session within the `createFromBlob(...)` method. Create the sql session before the loop and pass it as a parameter. That should improve the speed considerably.

Comment: I tried your approach, took 13 records for the test and there was 35 seconds of improvement, if I keep the DB connection alive for the whole time. Still I'll try with DB Connection pooling as suggested by @ramsinb, then I'll mark a correct answer. Thanks :)

Comment: You could also create multiple threads doing the same job. (You may have to lock records before a read from your old db so that other threads don't retrieve the same record and update it to the new one.) I'm not sure how connection pooling will improve your current speed. 1 or two connections as local variables should be  enough. Theoretically, if you use a connection pool, there is a small overhead (but i think negligible) of retrieving a connection from the pool each time you need one. With only 1 or 2 connections as variables, there isn't much overhead as compared to a connection pool.